# Using mod_rewrite to hide the .py extension of a Python script accessed on a web browser

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to hide the .py extension of a Python script loaded in a web browser and still have the script run. For example: typing `url.dev/basics/pythonscript` in the address bar fires pythonscript.py and shows the results in the browser window.

1. The URL url.dev/basics/pythonscript fetches the static file /pythonscript.py
2. The browser still displays the url url.dev/basics//pythonscript

Typing in `url.dev/basics/pythonscript.py` DOES work and the Python script results is displayed. I can also get mod_rewrite to rewrite `url.dev/basics/phpscript` to `url.dev/basics/phpscript.php` and run the PHP code successfully behind the scenes.

But `url.dev/basics/pythonscript` does NOT redirect to `url.dev/basics/pythonscript.py` **(I get a 404 Not Found)**.

**Background Info**

**A)** PHP rewriting works: the following in an .htaccess located in url.dev/basics/ WORKS for PHP scripts:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /basics/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

**B)** Python rewriting does NOT work: the following in an .htaccess located in url.dev/basics/ does NOT work for Python scripts **(I get a 404 Not Found)**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /basics/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.py -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.py
</IfModule>
```

**C)** I am a beginning programmer working through **Exercise 2: Your first program** in the [Basics section of Software Engineering for Internet Applications](http://philip.greenspun.com/seia/basics). I am trying to follow the recommendation to use an execution environment where  'One URL = one file', but want to use Python rather than PHP. *I realize that this is not the best way to build a web application down the line. It is only a convention to be used during the initial part of the course linked above.*

**D)** I set up the Virtual Hosts development environment in OS 10.6 Snow Leopard so that I can access my development at url.dev as per 'Hacky Holidays' at adactio.com. My Python version is Python 2.6.1.

**E)** I plan to use Django eventually, but want to work on simpler code first if possible so I can better understand what is going on.

**F)** I have the following in my httpd.conf:

```
TypesConfig /private/etc/apache2/mime.types
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

and:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so
```

**G)** My Apache version (seen in server log after restarting the server): *Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.1 mod_fastcgi/2.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations*

Looking forward to any help!

Comment: please define "does not work" in step B. Very good problem description otherwise.

Comment: `C` is absolute nonsense. One URL = one file? That sort of thing would make a CMS - or any database-managed site - completely impossible.

Comment: if you change `One URL = one file` to `one page = one url` I'd agree, but that has nothing do with actual files.

Comment: Enable the [rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and post the logging output that results from accessing `url.dev/basics/pythonscript`. Also, what are you using to run your Python scripts? mod_wsgi or mod_python (or something else)? What about the PHP scripts - mod_php I assume?

Comment: @pixeline: I get a 404 not found. I've now updated the question stating this.

@Daniel Roseman and @Wrikken: I've updated C) to clarify.

@David Zazlavsky: I will keep trying to enable rewrite log, but so far it is giving me an Internal Server Error when I put it in the same .htaccess as above. I have the following lines uncommented in my httpd.conf file (I assume libphp5.so is running php stuff, and mod_fastcgi.so is running python stuff):
<code>LoadModule php5_module  libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule fastcgi_module  libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so</code>. See the newly-added F) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: I needed to add the application MIME type so that the Apache Web Server understands it should run the code.

In url.dev/basics/.htaccess add:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-py .py
</IfModule>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache: `sudo apachectl graceful`

And it works! http://url.dev/basics/pythonscript runs the code in pythonscript.py! Note that I'm *not* sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works.

Here is my complete .htaccess file:

```
# Options +ExecCGI
# SetHandler cgi-script

<IfModule mime_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-py .py
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /basics/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.py -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.py
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are running on a linux box, dont use mod-rewrite - rename the script.

you can call the script - pythonscript not pythonscript.py

you add to the first line of the script 
 pointing to your python interpreter

and set the file to be executable

with

```
chmod +x pythonscript
```

when the file is executed - it will read the first line of the file
and execute the interpeter in the first line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and then set the directory to execute the script

to make this work, you change the files in the directory executable in your .htaccess file

```
basics/.htaccess
-----------
Options +ExecCGI
SetHandler cgi-script
-----------
```

Your python script will look like this

```
basics/pythonscript 
-------
#!/usr/bin/python

print "STATUS: 200 OK\n\n" 


print "hello world"
------
```

Warning... You may get an error in your error_log file that looks like this.

```
[Thu Aug 05 19:26:34 2010] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /home/websites/testing/htdocs/basics/.htaccess: Option ExecCGI not allowed here
```

If that happens your webserver is not allowing the changes from your .htaccess file

Your webserver will need to be able to allow changes in your htaccess file 
so you may need to enable Allowoverride All in your httpd.conf file

```
<Directory "/">

.... 

Allowoverride All

</Directory>
```

Comment: I'm running on OS X and tried your idea anyway. Still does not work (I get a 404 trying to access url.dev/basics/pythonscript). The server error log says *[Fri Aug 06 08:44:45 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /Users/simon/Sites/url.dev/basics/p (None could be negotiated).* I did restart the server after changing .htaccess to include only the lines you wrote above. Thank you for trying, I appreciate it.

Comment: Why does it say "/Users/simon/Sites/url.dev/basics/p"

That is not your script name... 

what happens when you copy the script to "p" in that directory.. 

can you shell exec the file in that directory with your terminal

cd /Users/simon/Sites/url.dev/basics

./pythonscript 

and then after you rename try 

./p 

see if they both work... 

Once we confirm they work - we can finish your webserver config

but it is best to make sure your scripts work first..

Comment: I was getting tired of typing 'pythonscript' and renamed it to 'p'. I apologize for not mentioning this.