# Hide the python script part in the url

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have been looking around and found tons on informations and posts about this argument, but every solution I have tried has failed for me. 
So I decided to ask posting my specific scripts here.

I'm deploying on my share host (bluehost) this application written in python with pylons: www.rhodecode.org

Everything works, a little slow because apparently bluehost don't support mod_wsgi, so I have to use standard cgi, but it works and this are my python (cgi) script and .htaccess

```
#!/usr/bin/python

activate_this = '/home2/danielen/rhodecode-venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))


import wsgiref.handlers
from paste.deploy import loadapp

myapp = loadapp('config:/home2/danielen/rhodecode/production.ini')

wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(myapp)
```

---

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.py$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.py [L]
</IfModule>
```

As I said everything works, but anytime I go to rhodecode.danieleniero.com the url change in rhodecode.danieleniero.com/index.py (and eventually something more after that)

I would really like to always hide the /index.py/ part if possible and everything I have tried so far don't work or break the link.

Thank you,
    Dan

Comment: Perhaps this should help you out:

[Using mod_rewrite to hide the .py extension of a Python script accessed on a web browser][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418687/using-mod-rewrite-to-hide-the-py-extension-of-a-python-script-accessed-on-a-web

Comment: Thank you Prahalad but as I said I have tried many things and this is one of the posts that I have found during my research.

Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case and I got a 500 Internal Server Error out of it.

Comment: Just because you got a 500 doesn't mean that's not how you do it. Did you bother to check the error log?

Comment: Before anything, I should clarify that I have practically none experience with Apache configuration and web technology in general.
So I don't even know where this logs could be...

Said that, if you are sugesting that the script could be wrong, I would discard this idea, because in the form I sent it above, the site works, I just got that annoying index.py always visible

Comment: Or you could use the new hosted RhodeCode service at [https://rhodecode.com](https://rhodecode.com). It's initiated by the core developers of RhodeCode, works out-of-the-box and already serves the new RhodeCode 2.0 (aka RhodeCode Enterprise).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, but I want a self hosted tool because I want to host in in my share space and do what I please with it.
If I wanted to go for a commercial product probably I would go for BitBucket.